# Why is my ::before pseudo-element not working?

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble using the `::before` pseudo-element. In my pen, I'm using the `::before` and `::after` selectors to give my divs slanted edges. On the first div, this seems to work fine. But, on the second div, the slant is only stretching 50% of the width of the div. Here's my code:

```css
.services {
    text-align: center;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #F1F2B5 , #135058);
    height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.services::before {
    content: "";
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #F1F2B5 , #135058);
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    transform: skewY(-5deg);
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
    z-index: -1;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.box-alt {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 3px solid grey;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="services">
  <h2>Services</h2>
  <hr />
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="box-alt">hi</div>
    <div class="box-alt">hi</div>
    <div class="box-alt">hi</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, here's the link to my pen: http://codepen.io/Hudson_Taylor11/pen/XpBMwM?editors=0100

Comment: `::before` is a pseudo-**element** not a pseudo-*class*. Just sayin'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing `left: 0` on the `::before` style rule.  I think it defaults to `auto` which is not the same value.

Here's the details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left#Values

It does default to `auto`, which MDN describes as follows:

> Is a keyword that represents:
>   for absolutely positioned elements, the position of the element based on the right property and treat width: auto as a width based on the content.

I'm not entirely certain how that gets calculated and some browsers seem to interpret that differently.  I think FF will (or used to) leave `absolutely` positioned elements with an `auto` `left` and `right` where they normally would appear if they were `static`, but I'd have to build some tests to be sure.  In any case, it's generally a good idea to always explicitly set left, right, or both to reduce ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly. Just curious, why did I need to do that for the first, but not the second div?

Comment: @H.Allen Honestly, I'm not sure.  It has to do with how the browser interprets the calculated values of left and right.  I updated the answer with some more info, but I'd have to do more research to find out exactly why it does this.  You could also check in the CSS (or JavaScript because it's more popular) chat on here to ask those guys.  They have a lot more knowledge and experience than I do.